# No-Install Version of QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation

Is there a no-install version of QGIS? I'd like to be able to download the application and launch it without having to run through the install process. This would be for Windows only at first.

Comment: There aren't many apps you can run on Windows that don't require registry settings. QGIS seems like a poor candidate for such honors.

Comment: Its more about running the install process. I found this and am testing it now. https://github.com/pigreco/QGIS_portable_3x